# Gunicorn Gevent Running Python3.7

Tags: python, webserver, gunicorn

I am running gunicorn web server inside my virtual env and i am getting the below error

```
python --version
Python 3.7.0b3
```

Running using below command:

```
gunicorn  -w 1  -k gevent   --timeout 120 -b  0.0.0.0:8088 --limit-request-line 0 --limit-request-field_size 0  --statsd-host localhost:8125 "superset.app:create_app()" --log-level "debug"
```

My Output:

```
Error: class uri 'gevent' invalid or not found: 

[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "superset/envsuperset/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 99, in load_class
    mod = importlib.import_module('.'.join(components))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 726, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "superset-prod/envsuperset/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 14, in <module>
    import gevent
  File "superset-prod/envsuperset/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from gevent.os import fork
  File "superset-prod/envsuperset/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/os.py", line 495, in <module>
    _raw_posix_spawnp = os.posix_spawnp
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'posix_spawnp'
```

Comment: What's the OS you are running this program on?

Comment: @TinNguyen `ubuntu-1804`

Comment: Any solutions, yet?